# Django Generic detail view 'class' must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf while trying to delete an object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In my Django app, I'm trying to delete a Comment which is associated with a post, but I keep getting this error message.
The expected output is for the Comment to be deleted from the site and the database.

Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
Generic detail view CommentDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

I am new to Django and I don't know how to resolve this error.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CommentCreateView, CommentDeleteView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='add-comment'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment_delete/<int:comment_pk>/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
]
```

CommentDeleteView:

```
class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/comment_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'comment'

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        return comment.author == self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.post.pk})

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super().get_object(queryset=queryset)
        return get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=obj.pk)
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

Html template where the Delete Comment button is located:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                    <article class="media content-section">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="article-metadata">
                                <small class="text-muted">Posted: {{ comment.date_posted|date:"H:i, j F, Y" }}</small>
                                {% if comment.author == user or post.author == user%}
                                <div>
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'comment-delete' post_pk=post.pk comment_pk=comment.pk %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Delete Comment</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                {% endif%}
                            </div>
                            <div class="article-content">
                                <a class="article-title" href="#">{{ comment.content }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                {% endfor%}
```

I don't know how to approach this problem. I expected the comment to be deleted and to be redirected to the post page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_object` should return the object for the `comment_pk` where the `post_id` and `author` match, so:

```
class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/comment_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'comment'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.post.pk})

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Comment,
            pk=self.kwargs['comment_pk'],
            post_id=self.kwargs['post_pk'],
            author=self.request.user,
        )
```